# How do I put an NSMutableArray array into a string

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have an NSMutableArray with data that I need to convert into a NSString.

```
 data = [NSMutableArray array];



   Content string to write out to text file. 
   NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Log \nDevice Id Number: %@ \n=====Data    received from device %@====\n    Moves:     Miles:  \n \n \n \n====Data sent to Portal %@====\n    Moves:     Miles:  \n \n \n \n====Data received to  %@====\n    Response \n\n  ",serialNumber, dateString, dateString, dateString];

       [self setStatus:@"Syncing data..."];
self.userInfo = [self.cloud Authenticate:[self serialNumber]];

if ( self.deviceInfo )
{
    data = [self.device GetData:&error];
    if ( !data )
    {
        [self displayErrorMessage:error];
        data = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    // Getting sync data
    NSString *path = [@"~" stringByExpandingTildeInPath] ;
    path=[path stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/Movband Reports/"];

    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/movbandData.txt",path];
    NSString *content=[data componentsJoinedByString:@"-"]; // Sync data
```

Comment: How is the `data` array related to the variables used in `stringWithFormat`?

Comment: Array of custom objects, or strings, or....?

Comment: I'm trying to add data to the stringWithFormat. I need the data's out put

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data(array) has strings, and want to append it by some character/string use

```
NSString *content=[data componentsJoinedByString:@"-"];
```

Or, you can iterate through `data` and keep on appending on some conditions(that you know, which index has what value)

```
NSMutableString *content=[NSMutableString new];
for(NSInteger i=0; i<data.count; i++){
     switch(i){
         case 0:[content appendString:@"Device Id Number: %@"];
                break;
          case 1:[content appendString:@"=====Data    received from device %@"];
                break;
          case 2:[content appendString:@"Moves:     Miles:  \n \n \n \n====Data sent to Portal"];
                break;
          case 3:[content appendString:@" Moves:     Miles:  \n \n \n \n====Data received to  %@"];
                break;
     }
     [content appendString:data[i];
}
```

Comment: @DrummerB: that is why i edited, just before you hit "Save Edits" :)

Comment: Seems to work, but I'm not seeing any data? I'll post more code above.

Comment: nslog content, and check if it  got the values

Comment: getting error with  [content appendString:data[i]; sending pic

Comment: which XCode are you using?

Comment: i guess you are using older compiler... so write  `[content appendString:[data objectAtIndex:i]];`